# How to make HTML helper method fire eveytime partial view is rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a view ( for creating a recipe ) to which I dynamically add a partial view ( representing products ). There can be several products added to recipe. Partial view is added on button click, using jQuery, and this works fine:

```
    $('.loadPartial').on('click', function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();

    var $productsDiv = $('#productsDiv'),
        url = $(this).data('url');

    $.get(url, function (data) {
        $productsDiv.append(data);
    });
});
```

Partial view has a combo. Name of this combo is generated dynamically using Html helper extension method 'GetIndexedName' which adds unique index to specified name. If I click button twice it should render two partial views, after first click combo name should be "ProductsCombo0", after the second "ProductsCombo1"

```
@Html.DropDownList( 
    @Html.GetIndexedName("ProductsCombo"), 
    null, 
    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control col-md-3" }
)
```

The problem is that the method @Html.GetIndexedName fires **only after the first button click** ( checked in debugger ). Next clicks only render partial view, but do use the method to generate name. All combos have name "ProductsCombo0", "ProductsCombo0"

Do you know how to make it fire everytime partial view is rendered?

If it can`t be done this way could you recommend me some other solution for generating unique ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to the problem. Data from AJAX call was cached and that is why function was called only once. All I had to do was to disable it. So I changed jQuery 'get' mehtod to 'post' which (  what i know ony now ) is not cached.

Answer (score 0):

Because every time you make the ajax call for a new row, It is a totally separate http call and this call does not have any information whether you are making the call for the **first or eighth row**. You need to store this value(*which row you are making this call for*) and use that when you build the dropdown name.

So first update your action method to accept a row index value.

```
public ActionResult AddRow(int id)
{
    var vm = new AddItemVm {RowIndex = id};
    vm.Items = new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
        new SelectListItem {Value = "1", Text = "IPhone"}
    };
    return PartialView("_NewItem", vm);
}
```

I am having  small view model to pass the data between my action method and the partial view, which looks like,

```
public class AddItemVm
{
    public int RowIndex { set; get; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Items { set; get; }
}
```

And in the partial view, which is strongly typed to our view model, we will read the `Model.RowIndex` property and use that to build the dropdown name/id.

```
@model YourNamespaceHere.AddItemVm
<div>
    @Html.DropDownList("ProductsCombo"+Model.RowIndex, Model.Items)
</div>
```

Now we need to make sure that we are sending a unique row index value to our AddRow method every time we want to add a new row. You can keep a javascript variable and increment it's value everytime user tries to add a new row and use that value.

```
$(function () {

    var rowIndex = 0;
    $('.loadPartial').on('click', function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();
        rowIndex++;
        var $productsDiv = $('#productsDiv'),
            url = $(this).data('url') + '/' + rowIndex;

        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $productsDiv.append(data);
        });
    });
});
```